# How to fix this SQL syntax error in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

This SQL command:

```
SELECT pno,COUNT (DISTINCT sno) AS supplier_count
FROM spj
GROUP BY pno;
```

gives me below error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT sno) AS supplier_count FROM spj GROUP BY pno' at line 1

How to fix this error?

Comment: Hi Rashmika, did you try to check the documentation as suggested? also try COUNT(DISTINCT sno) without space. In the future, try to add context and your research to the questions you ask.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space between the `COUNT` and `()`:

```
SELECT pno, COUNT(DISTINCT sno) AS supplier_count
FROM spj
GROUP BY pno;
```